# MVC confusion when it comes to lists and db

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement MVC for my Java desktop application and I am not very familiar with it. For the purpose of the question, I am considering a use case in which you click "refresh" button, it queries DB for list of students and update students lists. Here are my questions that have been confusing me:

1-For querying the DB, does it happen in the controller or in the model? My gut feeling says its controller who queries and once results are received, it updates the model. However I read in many posts that the Model is the one who knows its state transitions and does its updates!

2- Who creates the the view and model? Does the controller create them or are they created externally and passed to the controller?

3-In the above use case, does the model consists of an ArrayList of Students or is the model just a Student object but the Controller has and ArrayList of models?

Please help a fellow developer

Comment: Whoever downvoted, care to say why ? It is a very valid question

Comment: Please limit your posts to one question per post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For querying the DB, does it happen in the controller or in the model?

Short answer, querying the database happens in the model.

A List of Student is the model for the GUI, where Student is a Java object containing the student information.  The list of students is also the model for the database.

There are different ways you can approach the interaction between the list of students and the database.  One way is to read all of the student information at the beginning of your GUI initialization.  As your users interact with the GUI, your GUI controller inserts, updates, and marks students for deletion in the GUI model.  Finally, when the user closes the GUI, you write all of the changes in the list of students to the database.  This way, while simple, exposes you to data corruption if your GUI abends.  Also, only one person can make changes to the database at a time.

A better way is to read all of the student information at the beginning of your GUI initialization, as before.  As your users interact with the GUI, the GUI controller updates the list of students in the GUI model.  After each insert, update, or delete, you call the appropriate methods in the data access object to insert, update, or delete the student information, respectively.

> Who creates the the view and model?

You do.  :-)

The model / view / controller pattern is not just for organizing code.  Generally, you create the first cut of the model first.  Then you create the view, and add the fields to the model that you forgot when you created the first cut.  Lastly, you create the controller.  The controller(s) should do nothing but execute methods in the model to update the model and methods in the view to repaint / revalidate the view.

You pass an instance of the model and an instance of the view to your controller(s).  You should only have one instance of the model and one instance of the view.  However, they are not singletons.

> In the above use case, does the model consists of an ArrayList of Students or is the model just a Student object but the Controller has and ArrayList of models?

Finally, an easy question.  Neither.

Your model is a **List** of Student.  The List interface will be implemented by the ArrayList class.  Something like this.

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

By using the interface, you can easily change the ArrayList to a LinkedList, or your own implementation of the List interface.

A general Java rule is to use the interface unless the methods you need are only defined in the concrete class.

I hope this was helpful.